# Form_for - Rails error - Phone Number not saving to database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have the strangest error happening right now. I have a super basic form and it takes in first_name, Last_name, Email and Phone_number. It couldn't be more straight forward, but for a reason that is beyond me the Phone_number field is not working? Here is my code

```
<%= form_for @subscriber do |form| %>
 <div class="form-group">
<%= form.label :first_name %>
<%= form.text_field :first_name %>
<%= form.label :last_name %>
<%= form.text_field :last_name %>
<%= form.label :email %>
<%= form.text_field :email %>
<%= form.label :phone_number %>
<%= form.text_field :phone_number %>
</div>
<%= form.submit "Sign Up", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

Here is my model

```
class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates :first_name, presence: true
 validates :last_name, presence: true
 validates :email, presence: true
 validates :phone_number, presence: true
end
```

and schema

```
  create_table "subscribers", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "first_name"
t.string   "last_name"
t.string   "email"
t.string   "phone_number"
```

This is the result after I type in the data in the view. I obviously put a string in before I pressed sign up.

[image]

What am I missing? Any help would be great! If I take off the validation and type a string in it returns "nil" in the console?

Comment: can you post your controller code?

Comment: I just figured it out. it was my params I was including in the private function. You can post that advice in the answer if you want and I'll get you the points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default all values in params hash are unavailable in Rails4. You need to tell, which params are permitted to mass-assign in the :subscribers, if You want to submit the form (strong parameters). In Rails4 params must be listed (in hash), which ones to permit, before using them. And each controller manages its own list of permitted attributes. Therefore, in the controller You should use:

```
params.require(:subscribers).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, I guess the problem will be in your controller. For example maybe you forgot to permit `:phone_number`. make sure you do

```
params.require(:subscribers).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone_number)
```

Comment: why we `make sure this method is public`?